# Configuration of CloudAMQP Connection

Tags: cloudbees

I'm having difficulty configuring my connection to CloudAMQP in my deployed grails application.  I can run the application locally against a locally installed RabbitMQ instance but can't figure out how to correctly define my application to run on CloudBees using the CloudAMQP service.

In my Config.groovy, I'm defining my connection info and a queue:

```
rabbitmq {
    connectionfactory {
        username = 'USERNAME'
        password = 'PASSWORD'
        hostname = 'lemur.cloudamqp.com'
    }

    queues = {
        testQueue autoDelete: false, durable: false, exclusive: false
    }
}
```

When the application starts and tries to connect, I see the following log messages:

```
2013-08-23 21:29:59,195 [main] DEBUG listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer  - Starting Rabbit listener container.
2013-08-23 21:29:59,205 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG listener.BlockingQueueConsumer  - Starting consumer Consumer: tag=[null], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2013-08-23 21:30:08,405 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] WARN  listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer  - Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitUtils.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitUtils.java:112)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:163)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:228)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:119)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:109)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:199)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:524)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:106)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:102)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:124)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:381)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:516)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:545)
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; reason: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:343)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:216)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:118)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:95)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:131)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:508)
2013-08-23 21:30:08,406 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] INFO  listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer  - Restarting Consumer: tag=[null], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2013-08-23 21:30:08,406 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG listener.BlockingQueueConsumer  - Closing Rabbit Channel: null
2013-08-23 21:30:08,407 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG listener.BlockingQueueConsumer  - Starting consumer Consumer: tag=[null], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
Aug 23, 2013 9:30:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'grails'
Aug 23, 2013 9:30:11 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8634
Aug 23, 2013 9:30:11 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8634
```

Comment: I've tried to connect using the RabbitMQ api directly with the CLOUDAMQP_URL_ pattern and get a connection refused exception.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/CloudAMQP

when you bind your CloudAMQP service to your app - some config params are provided in the pattern of CLOUDAMQP_URL_ - this is the type of thing you would need to put in your config files so they can be wired in when the app launches.

Comment: I'm using the rabbitmq plugin for grails and it doesn't appear to support connection configuration through a URL.  I've tried to configure the connection using the hostname, username and password but it's not working.  The same configuration works correctly against a locally running rabbitmq instance.

Comment: a rabbitMQ in the cloud should be the same - as long as you can specify a hostname - are you saying it can't?

Comment: I am specifying the hostname, username and password but getting this Connection Reset error.  The same configuration works when running against a local RabbitMQ server.

Comment: can you try it locally against your CloudAMQP service?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to specify the virtualHost for CloudAMQP connections.  That worked for me.